# gradients only showing at white to black in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, linear-gradients

I have a gradient I've applied to a div, it's a very light grey to a slightly darker grey, and it works for every browser except IE8.  I don't have access to the css so I've had to apply these styles with jquery but they seem to work for every other browser so I'm not sure why it doesn't for IE.  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Build your CSS.
var gradient1 = {
    "background": "-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%, #f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient2 = {
    "background": "-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient3 = {
    "background": "-o-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient4 = {
    "background": "-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%); /* IE10+ */ background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient5 = {
    "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fbfbfb, endColorstr=# f4f4f5)"
};
var gradient6 = {
    "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#fbfbfb', endColorstr='#f4f4f5')"
};
var blue_background = {
    "background": "#eff5f8"
};


//Apply your CSS to the body tag.  You can enter any tag here, as
//well as ID's and Classes.
$(".gradient_1").css(gradient1);

$(".gradient_2").css(gradient2);

$(".gradient_3").css(gradient3);

$(".gradient_4").css(gradient4);

$(".gradient_5").css(gradient5);

$(".gradient_6").css(gradient6);


$(".blue").css(blue_background);

});
```

and then I've applied all of the classes to the div, gradient 1-6.  The html for the div is:

```
<div class="gradient_1 gradient_2 gradient_3 gradient_4 gradient_5 gradient_6"   
style="width: 690px; zoom: 1; display: block; margin-bottom: 15px; height: 100%;  
padding-top: 15px;">
```

and the page is http://www.brighamandwomens.org/Patients_Visitors/pcs/rehabilitationservices/mock/about.aspx  thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Gradients are not supported by IE 8.  You'll have to use a single color or supply a background-image

Comment: huh, that's strange because it displays a gradient with that code, it's just the wrong colors